# RegEx to match 2 or more digits in a string

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, re2

Suppose I have strings like:

```
ABC-L-W7P-1423
ABC-L-W7E-87
CH-L-W7-756
```

I need to grab the number at the end. That number might be 2, 3 or 4 digits. But currently what I have is:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(B2,"[^0-9]","")
```

Which of course also grabs the '7' in 'W7P' which I don't want.
EDIT:

I also need to match something like this:

```
CH-M-311-MM
```

So always a 2, 3 or 4 (or 5) digit number, but I need single digits excluded.

Comment: `=REGEXREPLACE(B2,"[0-9]{2,4}$","")`

Comment: This works - thankyou - but I've added new info. The number I need isn't necessary at the end of the string...

Comment: Try `=REGEXEXTRACT` with `\b[0-9]{2,4}\b`: `=REGEXEXTRACT(B2, "\b[0-9]{2,4}\b")`

Comment: @Wiktor that works great - thankyou!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `=REGEXEXTRACT` with `\b[0-9]{2,4}\b`:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(B2, "\b[0-9]{2,4}\b")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qM3mU4/1).

**Details**:

- `\b` - a leading word boundary
- `[0-9]{2,4}` - 2 to 4 digits
- `\b` - trailing word boundary

In case your 2-4 digits are always preceded with `-`, you may use

```
=REGEXREPLACE(B2,"^.*-([0-9]{2,4})\b.*","$1")
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qM3mU4/2)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `.*-` - any 0+ chars up to the last `-` that is followed with...
- `([0-9]{2,4})` - (Group 1 referred to with `$1` in the replacement pattern) - 2 to 4 digits
- `\b` - a trailing word boundary
- `.*` - any chars up to the end of string.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure which language you use, but if it supports lookarounds, you can assert that there is a `-` (dash) on the left side.

```
(?<=-)\d+
```

See: https://regex101.com/r/sI9zR9/1

Comment: RE2 regex library does not support lookarounds. Even a lookahead (`(?!...)`)